# Clearing Cookies of Google Gae in Terminal

Tags: google-app-engine

I used an email and uploaded to Google app engine , But now i want to use another email but my mac terminal is using my old email .I tried below code but it dont work.

```
appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update movie/1 --no_cookies
```

Some one please guide me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `.appcfg_cookies` file in your home directory.